# GO: How to solve "transport connection broken: too many transfer encodings: ["chunked" "chunked"]" error in a http response

Tags: go

The server is adding a double "chunked"transfer encoding, and I got this error message in my response. I don't have access to the server, by Postman the request returns the response normally, but version > 16.2 of Go is returning this error. The resp variable returns nil and the error variable returns "net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: too many transfer encodings: ["chunked" "chunked"]". Is it possible to modify the response encoding by the client?

```
    client := http.Client{}
    
    url := config.Ctx.ProtocolUrl + "http:localhost:4200/execution/9832138938"
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url,  nil)

    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        return nil
    } else {
        if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
            body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            defer resp.Body.Close()
            err = json.Unmarshal(body, &response)
            if err != nil {
                return response
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if `http.NewRequest()` returns an error? Also, take a look [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44591).

Comment: Yes, there is no error in http.NewRequest(). Thank you, I will take a look at the link

Comment: Why have `if err != nil { return nil } else {`? The `if` returns, just get rid of the `else`... it makes code look a lot cleaner, and perhaps add an `if resp.StatusCode != 200` block to output something in that case. if `er = json.Unmarshal()` shouldn't compile BTW... `er` is not declared

Comment: sorry, it's err, not er.

Answer (score -1):

After days of searching, technical reading and understanding that it is not a bug but that it should work that way, I have found a solution that does not involve installing a previous version or modifying the normal operation.

**Option 1**

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.Header.Set（"Accept-Encoding"，"identity")
client：= & http.Client {}
resp, _ := client.Do(req)
```

**Option 2**

```
tr := &http.Transport {
     DisableCompression：true，
}
client := &http.Client {Transport：tr}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
resp, _ := client.Do(req)
```

I found the solution and explanation at https://rarnu.xyz/archives/ktortogo. You will need to translate it first.